# Maximum number of applications on an IIS SERVER

Tags: iis

What is the maximum number of applications I can create within an iis server?
I am working on a project that will automatically create homologation environments, which will be destroyed after homologation, but I need to know if it will be possible to create as many environments as I think necessary for the tests

Comment: Google existing discussions. There is no hard limit as web apps vary by nature.

Comment: OK. My question is because I did not find an official information of microsoft, as for example I found about maximum number of databases that I can create in an instance of SqlServer (32766). thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no hard limit as web apps vary by nature. – Lex Li Feb 7 at
>   15:17